# I have a pre-computed hash of a pdf document, how to generate digital signature using the hash and stamping it on the document using pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I'm pretty new to the concept of digital signatures, signing etc.
Currently in a pickle, my problem description is as follows:

I have 2 different servers.
Server A : The pdf document is uploaded, a hash for this document is created using SHA-256 Algorithm with the MessageDigest interface. The hash is passed on to server B for generating the digital signature or signed hash. This signature from server B is then stamped on to the pdf document using pdfBox.

more details => The uploaded document is passed to pdfbox code (on server A) to attach a PDSignature to the document, the SignatureInterface is overwritten and the contents obtained as parameter from the sign() method (overriden method) is hashed using SHA-256, passed to server B to generate digital signature and then returned as byte[] in the sign() method. Pdfbox then goes ahead and stamps this signature to the document.

Server B : generates the digital signature using SHA256WithRSA algorithm with BouncyCastleFipsProvider.

I was expecting the signature to be certified as valid in Adobe. But, On opening the resulting document from Adobe, I get the following error
"The document is altered or modified"

Is my approach wrong? is there a different approach that could solve my problem ?
The required flow is => server A will generate a hash, server B will then generate the signature and server A will stamp this on the pdf document.

**An update** Just to add, I tried by simply passing the content bytes from pdfBox (without hashing) to server B and stamped the resulting signature on the pdf document, the signature is valid. But however the requirement strictly wants only the document hash to be passed from server A to  B and not the contents.

Comment: Why do not put everything on same server, that will help your signature to be fine

Comment: *"Is my approach wrong?"* - Yes. If I understand you correctly, you take the original PDF as-is and calculate its hash for signing. This is wrong, you have to prepare the original PDF for signing, a signature field must be set with a signature dictionary containing among other entries a dummy signature value, then this prepared PDF (except the dummy value) must be hashed, see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for details. Thus, PDFBox (which does this preparation) must be used from the start.

Comment: @mkl Thank you for your response. As far as I understand pdfbox already does this and passes it as content in overriden sign() method. I'm hashing the content bytes and not the pdf directly.  This is what i had mentioned under "more details" in my problem statement. This is the code snippet with just the hashing.

Comment: @Elikill58 Well its more of a business usecase

Comment: @mkl This is the code for the sign() method in the custom SIgnatureInterface of pdfbox (which gets invoked when document.saveIncremental() is executed). In this I perform hashing of the content using SHA-256. But I have also included the code snippet of the digital signature generation that happens on server B to give you more understanding on the algorithm that is being used.   https://github.com/johnskim9414/signPdf/blob/6d8cebe57e9b5fed2e3cc62649ecf4cd3a9e8049/src/main/java/com/sign/pdf/CustomSignature.java

Comment: Considering your update and your code you really appear to hash to often... maybe once less on server B would help.

Comment: @mkl yes, hashing cannot be removed at server A, so I was trying to remove it at server B but they aren't effective. can you please help me with a reference for separating hashing from encryption on server B? because all algorithms supported by bouncyCastle come with a combination of hashing and signing (ex: SHA256WithRSA).                                         
Also is it safe to just perform encryption on server B for generating digital signature? as through my research many people suggest that encryption depends on hashing algorithm properties to avoid collision attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [linked sources](https://github.com/johnskim9414/signPdf/blob/6d8cebe57e9b5fed2e3cc62649ecf4cd3a9e8049/src/main/java/com/sign/pdf/CustomSignature.java), your current hash signing on server B looks like this:

```java
/* Start : This is code snippet of the digital signature logic residing on server B */
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());
X509Certificate cert = getCertificate();
Certificate[] certificateChain = new Certificate[1];
certificateChain[0] = cert;
Store certs = new JcaCertStore(Arrays.asList(certificateChain));
CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
ContentSigner sha256Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(getPrivateKey());
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
    new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha256Signer, cert));
gen.addCertificates(certs);
CMSTypedData cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(hash);
CMSSignedData cms = gen.generate(cmsData, false);
byte[] signedHash = cms.getEncoded(); 
/* End : This is code snippet of the digital signature logic residing on server B */
```

But this considers your `hash` to be the data to sign, not a pre-calculated hash thereof, and calculates the digest of it internally. Thus, the resulting signature container does not sign your PDF but your `hash` bytes.

To make this code *not* calculate the digest itself but instead use your `hash` as pre-calculated digest, you have to replace the `DigestCalculatorProvider` returned by `new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()` with a custom implementation that provides `DigestCalculator` objects that constantly return `hash`.

For the normal BouncyCastle library such an implementation might look like this:

```java
public class PrecomputedDigestCalculatorProvider implements DigestCalculatorProvider {
    private final byte[] digest;

    public PrecomputedDigestCalculatorProvider(byte[] digest) {
        this.digest = digest;
    }

    @Override
    public DigestCalculator get(final AlgorithmIdentifier digestAlgorithmIdentifier) throws OperatorCreationException {

        return new DigestCalculator() {
            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                return new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getDigest() {
                return digest;
            }

            @Override
            public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
                return digestAlgorithmIdentifier;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You say you're using the FIPS variant of BouncyCastle. Thus, you may have to adapt the code somewhat.

Comment: Thank you mkl. Used your suggestion to implement a customDigestCalculator and by replacing the code,_gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha256Signer, cert));_  with   **gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new PrecomputedDigestCalculatorProvider(hash)).build(sha256Signer, cert));** But what should be passed as replacement to "hash" & the resulting "cmsData" in these two lines _CMSTypedData cmsData = new CMSProcessableByteArray(hash);
CMSSignedData cms = gen.generate(cmsData, false);_

Comment: I implemented the custom DigestCalculator **PrecomputedDigestCalculatorProvider** as suggested by mkl and modified the code as below : **gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                new PrecomputedDigestCalculatorProvider(hash)).build(sha256Signer, cert));
    CMSAbsentContent absentContent = new CMSAbsentContent();
    CMSSignedData cms = gen.generate(absentContent, false);** CMSAbsentContent object tells the CMSSignedDataGenerator that there is no actual content to be signed, and that only the hash value needs to be signed. This worked for me!

Comment: `CMSAbsentContent` sounds good. Theoretically you could use arbitrary content as you neither hash it (you're using a fixed hash after all) nor embed it in the signature container.