Digitally Sign pdf digest to pkcs7 signed hash using AWS cloudHSM
I need to sign a PDF using the PDFBox library and AWS CloudHSM.
In itext its working fine but while using some other way it is showing invalid signature.Below are the codes
Working code -:
public byte[] signUsingDigest(String digestBASE64,PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain) throws Exception {
            
     PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA256", manager.getProvider().getName());
     String hashAlgorithm = signature.getHashAlgorithm();
     BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
     PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, digest, false);
     byte[] hash = Base64.decodeBase64(digestBASE64);
     byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
     
     byte[] extSignature = signature.sign(sh);
     sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());

    // return sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null,PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
     byte[] pkcs7digitalSigned = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);
     return pkcs7digitalSigned;
}

But when i want to remove itext code with below code its showing invalid signature
public byte[] signUsingDigest(String digestBASE64, PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain ) throws Exception {

    byte[] hash = Base64.decodeBase64(digestBASE64);

    // Create the signed attributes using BouncyCastle
    CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    List<Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(chain);
    JcaCertStore certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
    ContentSigner sha256Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").setProvider(manager.getProvider().getName()).build(pk);
    generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
            new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha256Signer, (X509Certificate) chain[0]));
    generator.addCertificates(certs);

    CMSProcessableByteArray contentBytesCMS = new CMSProcessableByteArray(hash);
    CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(contentBytesCMS, false);

    return signedData.getEncoded();
}


Your iText based code signs the byte ranges. Your plain BouncyCastle based code signs a hash of the byte ranges.

Thanks @mkl , but how to convert hash to bytes range without itext

This answer shows how to use a CMSSignedDataGenerator with a pre-calculated hash of the data-to-sign (by setting a customized DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator). As that code is 7 years old, there might have been some BC API changes you have to follow up.

Hi @mkl , Thanks for your help , i took the reference of your previous solution. it works for me . Thanks you so much!

Great! Shall we mark your question as duplicate of that previous question then?

sure , really appreciate your help! Here is the reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75757770/i-have-a-pre-computed-hash-of-a-pdf-document-how-to-generate-digital-signature
